# Network request by hitting 2 APIs to display tableview data - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a tableview of data to be shown in the app.

For that, I should hit an API first, which will give me the list of data.

Then, I have to hit another api for each individual cell to get another piece of data I need to display it in the tableview for each cell.

I have used Alamofire and am done with getting the data from the first API. But, am stuck with how to get the data for each individual cell record from the second API.

1. Should I do the second request synchronously?
2. Also, there are 1000 of cell data from the first API. So, before rendering the UI, how will I do 1000 of requests to get data from the Second API?

Please help.

Comment: do you have to download all 1000 records at the same time? cant you just download the ones that are displaying in the table cell, or does the ws have to complete before you can show the cell?

Comment: it means you hit server at 1000 times, its worst and wrong scenario, do like initially ftech all data stored in local Db, or array, then if you select the particular cell get the data from that local Db, or array and show where you need.

Comment: I cannot store in db as the information is dynamic. I can display data for the cells that are in view. but, when should i do the network request. Should it be done like what we do for an image.

Comment: Call the api on every cell it is a wrong implementation instead of this, get all data in one API and implement pagination to get data from single api

e.g load bunch of 20-30 data in every page and call api when last cell will visible with your current page number

Comment: I do not have control over API side.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is after the 1st request has completed, try show the cells with the incomplete information but with some loading indicators to let the user know there is more info coming if you could not fetch already downloaded info.

Then each cell should kick off their own individual ws call to get the info from the 2nd api, but the tableview controller must listen for the response (not the cell because it may be recycled) so that even if the cell goes off screen, that response will still be processed and stored until a refresh occurs so if the cell comes back into view, you can load up the info without having to hit the ws again.

This way is basically giving you a way to lazy load the data.

Comment: you may also want to load up some cells info that is off the screen, maybe like 3 or so cells so that if the user scrolls down a bit the data is already pre-loaded

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Thanks. Am using Alamofire. It would be better if I can know how to make the tableview controller listen for the response which is done from the cell. Any code could help.

Comment: unfortunately i dont have experience with alamofire, but maybe the completion handler for the webservice response can just call a delegate method that the tableview has implemented

Comment: Ok. Thanks, Is there any other way other than this. I just want to make sure that i use the best way possible.

Comment: i think any other way would just call the 2nd api unnecessarily and waste data if the user doesnt intend to view every cell, lazy loading approach is usually the best way when there is a lot of data, but yeah as suggested in other comments, there is the paging approach which is similar to this but you dont have control over that it seems